# Module import error only when run from command line

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-import, python-venv

I can successfully run a python script from the IDE (PyCharm) but when I attempt to run this from the command line I get ModuleNotFoundError.

The module is `PythonGit` and is imported as follows after doing `pip install`:

```py
from git import Repo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Imported git package')
```

I have a virtual environment set up as `.venv/` and the package is present here:  `.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/git`.

The output of `pip list` is as follows:

```bash
Package            Version
------------------ -------
...
gitdb              4.0.9
GitPython          3.1.29
...
```

The virtual environment is activated when I attempt to run from the command line yet this is the error I am getting:

```bash
  File "/Users/paul/Repos/dependencies/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from git import Repo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'git'
```

There are no special settings in the run configuration in the IDE, the script path points to the same file (`main.py`) and the interpreter to the one in the virtual environment.

I have not been able to find any answer on these forums that successfully addresses this issue yet.

Comment: Is that the `pip list` before or after you activate your environment ?

Comment: This is afterwards

Answer (score 1):

I just tested and successfully ran the python program. 
Here are the steps I took:

---

- Open a **command prompt**
- Navigate to the folder that will host the virtual environment. In my case this was:

```
D:\Personal\Programming>_
```

- Checked **Python version**  using: **`py --version`**

```
D:\Personal\Programming>py --version
Python 3.10.8
```

- Upgraded **pip** using: **`py -m pip install --upgrade pip`**
- Checked **pip version** using: **`py -m pip --version`**

```
D:\Personal\Programming>py -m pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from ...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
```

- Ensured I had the latest **virtualenv** : **`py -m pip install --user virtualenv`**
- Create a new **virtual environment** (env) using : **`py -m venv env`**
- **Activated** the environment (env) using: **`.\env\Scripts\activate`**

The cursor now shows you are in the virtual enviroment:

```
(env) D:\Personal\Programming>_
```

Also you should see a new folder called **env** in the `D:\Personal\Programming` folder (or where ever you created the virtual environment.

[image: env folder]

- Checked that python existed within the virtual environment: **`where python`**

```
(env) D:\Personal\Programming>where python
D:\Personal\Programming\env\Scripts\python.exe
```

- Installed GitPython using: **`py -m pip install GitPython`**

```
(env) D:\Personal\Programming>py -m pip install GitPython
Collecting GitPython
  Using cached GitPython-3.1.29-py3-none-any.whl (182 kB)
Collecting gitdb<5,>=4.0.1
  Downloading gitdb-4.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 62.7/62.7 kB 3.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting smmap<6,>=3.0.1
  Using cached smmap-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Installing collected packages: smmap, gitdb, GitPython
Successfully installed GitPython-3.1.29 gitdb-4.0.10 smmap-5.0.0
```

- Checked pip list using: **`pip list`**

```
(env) D:\Personal\Programming>pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
gitdb      4.0.10
GitPython  3.1.29
pip        22.2.2
setuptools 63.2.0
smmap      5.0.0
```

- Created the **main.py** program in my **`D:\Personal\Programming`** folder
- Ran the **main.py** program: **`py main.py`**

```
(env) D:\Personal\Programming>py main.py
Imported git package
```

This shows that the program **ran successfully**.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  Let me re-create and see if I get the same results

Comment: How did you go ?

Comment: Yes, recreating as new project works fine.  Clearly an issue with the existing environment.  I deleted it and created a new virtual environment and all is good now.  Not an answer to what was wrong but at least a solution.

Comment: What did you do originally that was different from what was posted ? That might provide some clues?

Comment: Really useful set of steps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install using setup.py from this https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython
Just clone from git and run setup.py in ur directory